# BIML GetDatabaseSchema not working with ODBC Progress Source Database

Tags: odbc, progress, biml

I'm trying to generate an automated staging area with BIML.
The source database is Progress and is connected by ODBC.

I'm using the following walkthroughs: 
https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/07/12/biml-extension-methods-getdatabaseschema/

http://bimlscript.com/walkthrough/Details/3121

**1-2-Environment.biml:**

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
   <#@ template tier="0" #>

<Connections>
    <OleDbConnection Name="Source" ConnectionString="Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;" />
    <OdbcConnection Name="Source2" ConnectionString="DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;" />
    <OleDbConnection Name="Target" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=DWH_Staging;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</Connections>
<Databases>
    <Database Name="DWH_Staging" ConnectionName="Target" />
    <Database Name="pa" ConnectionName="Source" />
</Databases>
<Schemas>
    <Schema Name="test" DatabaseName="DWH_Staging" />
    <Schema Name="pub" DatabaseName="pa" />
</Schemas>
```

Source2 is the normal ODBC Connection, Source is a test by using OLEDB for ODBC.

**1-2-CreateTableMetadata.biml**

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement" #>

<#
var sourceConnection = RootNode.DbConnections["Source"];
var importResult = sourceConnection.GetDatabaseSchema();

#>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Tables>
    <# foreach (var table in importResult.TableNodes) { #>
    <Table Name="Staging_<#=table.Schema.Name#>_<#=table.Name#>" SchemaName="DWH_Staging.test">
      <Columns>
        <# foreach (var column in table.Columns) { #>
          <# if (column.DataType == System.Data.DbType.AnsiString) { #>
            <Column Name="<#=column.Name#>" DataType="String" Length="<#=column.Length#>">
              <Annotations>
                <Annotation AnnotationType="Tag" Tag="ConvertToUnicode">yes</Annotation>
              </Annotations>
            </Column>
          <# } else { #>
            <#=column.GetBiml()#>
          <# } #>
        <# } #>
      </Columns>
      <Annotations>
        <Annotation AnnotationType="Tag" Tag="SourceSchemaQualifiedName"><#=table.SchemaQualifiedName#></Annotation>
      </Annotations>
    </Table>
    <# } #>
  </Tables>
</Biml>
```

**1-x-DeployTargetTables.biml:**

```
<#@ template tier="2" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="MasterTableDeploy" ConstraintMode="Parallel">
      <Tasks>
        <# foreach (var table in RootNode.Tables) { #>
        <ExecuteSQL Name="Create <#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="Target">
          <DirectInput><#=table.GetDropAndCreateDdl()#></DirectInput>
        </ExecuteSQL>
        <# } #>
      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

The problem is, the generated MasterTableDeploy.dtsx package doesn't contain anything, it's just empty.
As a test I used our own SQL Server as a Source, which works perfectly fine.
Using the Progress ODBC Source doesn't do anything, no error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you or anybody else have access to the database logs? Usually dbname.lg. Perhaps they reveal something?

Comment: Hello, which logs do you mean? From Progress?

Comment: Exactly. There are at least one database log called "databasename.lg". If you use appserver there are also files named something like asbroker1.server.log and asbroker1.broker.log. These names are standard, but they can be renamed (apart from the database log).

Comment: Ok, I will try to contact the db admins, as I don't have access to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing logged in the *.lg-file or in the other files. Any other ideas?

Comment: You should talk to the db admins. Perhaps they can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem while trying to connect to a Db2 database using an ODBC connection. I ended up decompiling BimlEngine.dll and found out that this functionality is not implemented for ODBC connections.
Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If this is true, why don't they state this somewhere? We lost a few hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: Since you're including System.DB, you could try directly using the System.DB.ODBC.GetSchema() method (or System.DB.Oledb.GetSchema(), if OleDB is your poison...) and work from there.

I did something like this once in a Script Task to query a particular not-very-compliant "ODBC" driver/database for its schema objects...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but maybe it can help others.

There is an issue with some of the ODBC providers and GetDatabaseSchema(). For me ImportDB() (the older version of GetDatabaseSchema()) worked fine.